# Facing Issue in Payment API (Checkout Order) for Bigcommerce

Tags: android, ios, swift, api, bigcommerce

With Bigcommerce, I need to develop an mobile application and I was checking API Feasibility w.r.t API documentation provided by Bigcommerce.

**Checkout Order API**

Now, I tried few of them and now, I trying checkout order to create an order on postman but didn't get expected response by this document, though I was able to create cart, adding products, billing address and consignments.

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v3/storefront.html#postcheckoutorder

Probably, I am doing something wrong or mising concept of placing order via API.

**Steps**

I followed to initiate test checkout via API:

1. Created a testgateway on Bigcommerce to use dummy bank card as 4111111111111111
2. Enabled test credit card payments

[image: POSTMAN IMAGE FOR CHECKOUT API: Please click here]

As per my understanding for creating order in APP, I need to follow following steps. But for postman it should work.

1. Create an order
2. Implement Payment gateway in my APP
3. Then, create transaction

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v3/orders.html#createtransaction

Correct me, if I am wrong somewhere. That would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello @Gandhi , I am trying to do something similar. Were you able to achieve this? If yes please let me know how did you handle the checkout for your ios app? Did you took care of PCI compliance by yourself or you redirected the user to BC checkout page? It would be great if you can please help me.